# Why is this not defined when I defined it? (NameError)

Tags: python, nameerror

I am making a game, and this code is included. But somehow it is not defined when i defined it in the code clearly?

```
def do_action(self, action, **kwargs):
    action_method = getattr(self, action.method.__name__)
if action_method:
    action_method(**kwargs)
```

that is the code but it doesnt want to work as it says NameError: action_method is not defined. 
Please help

Comment: If the indentation of your code is correct, it's because the `if action_method:` is _outside_ the function (and it's a variable local to the `do_action()` function).

Comment: If your code is identical to what you've posted, you have poor indentation and it's causing the `NameError`.  The `action_method` is only available inside your `do_action` function.

Comment: You have defined 'action_method' within the scope of the function 'do_action'. Outside such function it is not known. The indentation is likely wrong.

Comment: Ah yes thank you got it now :)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're defining this function inside of a class since you included "self" as an argument to the function. If this is your intention, then to access to function you need to do it through an instance of that class

```
class ExampleClass:

    def do_action(self, action, **kwargs):
        action_method = getattr(self, action.method.__name__)
        if action_method:  #Also, i think you had an indent problem here when pasting?
            action_method(**kwargs)

instance = ExampleClass()
instance.do_action('action')
```

You might also want to check out this article about class methods, instance methods, and static methods. That way you can pick the one that helps you accomplish what you're looking to do. https://realpython.com/instance-class-and-static-methods-demystified/

Comment: Thanks for your help :)